# NFC example

Tags: android

Здравствуйте, друзья!
Есть транспортная карта и телефон с NFC чипом, при их соединении телефон реагирует. Скачал приложение TagInfo, удалось даже какую-то информацию получить! Хочу написать приложение, которое бы показывало остаток поездок. Может кто-нибудь посвятить в тонкости, дать простенький пример?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Начинаем читать с стандартной [документации](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/index.html). Там даже примеры есть. Там узнаем, что есть стандартные классы для этого - [android.nfc.*](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/package-summary.html). А потом узнаем, что в стандартных демках, поставляемых с сдк, есть примеры под названием NFCdemo.

Answer (score 0):

[Есть готовое приложение для этого](http://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=264190)

Comment: Вы уверенны, что нужна пассивная эмуляция nfc?

Comment: Человеку нужно читать. И сторонними программами у него это получается. Для определенных задач пассивная эмуляция нужна, но  нужна ли она для его задачи?

Comment: и как готовое приложение мне поможет написать свое? Оно к тому же не работает с моей транспортной картой!

Comment: а в вопросе Вы написали противоположное "получилось даже какую-то информацию получить! "

Раз то приложение как то заработало, значит работать можно. Теперь осталось найти спецификации в Вашей карте или подобрать опытным путем.

Comment: @katso декомпелировать, посмотреть как оно работает и переписать, добавляя что-то своё