# Id NFC метки

Tags: java, android, nfc

Здравствуйте, как сделать так, чтобы при наведении смарта к NFC метке в тост выводился его ID?

Answer (score 1):

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/181917#181922

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример кода для получения идентификатора NFC-метки в качестве строки:

```java
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
       String uid = byteArrayToHexString(intent.getByteArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_ID));
       //ну а тут выводите ID в тост
}

public static String byteArrayToHexString(byte[] inarray) {
    int i, j, in;
    String[] hex = {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"};
    String out = "";

    for (j = 0; j < inarray.length; ++j) {
         in = (int) inarray[j] & 0xff;
         i = (in >> 4) & 0x0f;
         out += hex[i];
         i = in & 0x0f;
         out += hex[i];
    }
    return out;
}
```